# Check If Value Exists In Another Column And Highlight In VBA

Tags: vba

I have 500 value in column A and 200 value in column B. I need to check that column A values are present in column B. if value is found then need to highlight that founded value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my attempt. Your questions is pretty vague though, so there are a few assumptions. Good luck!

```
Sub compareColumns()

   ' im assuming the sheet in question is the  index 1 sheet in the workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

   ' im assuming no header
   Dim lastRowA As Integer: lastRowA = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   Dim lastRowB As Integer: lastRowB = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

   Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
   Dim matchMe As String
   For i = 1 To lastRowA
       matchMe = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
    
       For j = 1 To lastRowB
           If ws.Cells(j, 2).Value = matchMe Then
               ws.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
               Exit For
           End If
       Next j
   Next i
End Sub
```